# VFP Grid with multiselect

Tags: grid, multi-select, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to implement multiple record selection feature on a grid.
It is very similar to http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3831
It adds an extra column with check boxes. I want those check boxes!!

But it depends on a extra logical field in the underlying table. It need to create a class clscheck which inherits CHECKBOX. I'm not sure why this CLICK procedure is needed for the checkbox.

```
 PROCEDURE CLICK
    IF DODEFAULT()
        KEYBOARD '{DNARROW}'
    ENDIF
 ENDPROC
```

When I removed it, row selection did not work correctly as expected. Why this?

Here is my requirement:
1) I don't want to add an extra logical field in the underlying table.
2) To work with controls in the grid, I think AllowCellSelection must be .T. I want **AllowCellSelection = .F.** because I don't need to work with any control in the grid except the check boxes. I need to work only with check boxes. The other columns will be read-only.
3) Can I have selected list without the logical field in the underlying table?
4) Can I remove the usage of KEYBOARD '{DNARROW}'?

In fact, I have a grid which is **AllowCellSelection = .F.**, but it only provides single selection.
I need to enhance it with multiple selection, thus, I just want to add an extra column with check boxes so that user can know he can select multiple records.
No need Shift+Click or Ctrl+Click which is not familiar with idiot users.

I have found this - http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=433
It also depends on an extra logical field and it depends Shift+Click and Ctrl+Click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is quite common for multi-select grids.  I've used them SIMILAR to this in the past.  However, you are afraid of the extra column in the underlying table.  That may/not be true.  You don't always have to update the ORIGINAL table, but a temporary CURSOR you are presenting to the user.  Ex: If you want to display a list of employees in a table.  No, you don't want to keep adding this column to the original employee table as then anyone else trying to do multi-select could falsely get your selection.  However, if you pulled into your own local cursor and presented to the user, then no problem.  Example...

```
Thisform.YourGrid.RecordSource = "Employees"
(bound directly to your employee table -- not necessarily the right thing)
```

vs

```
use in select( "C_MultiPickEmployees" )
select ;
      .F. as IsChosen, ;
      E.* ;
   from ;
      Employees E;
   into ;
      cursor C_MultiPickEmployees READWRITE

Thisform.YourGrid.RecordSource = "C_MultiPickEmployees"
```

NOW, you have your extra column without dealing with issues to the underlying table.  If you wanted to further filter what you were showing -- such as employees for a certain division/department, then just add that to a WHERE clause, add an Order By if so needed and you are good to go.

As for the "Allow Cell Selection", I've never had to deal with that.  I just add a "checkbox" to the first column and set

Thisform.YourGrid.Column[1].CurrentControl = "CheckBoxControl"
(based on the name it is added to the column).

Then, set the column 1's "ControlSource" = "C_MultiPickEmployees.IsChosen" and you should mostly be done.

As for the "CLICK" event trying to force the down arrow.  This is more for automatically scrolling to the next record so you can just click, click, click for multiple entries.

Hope this helps clarify things for you.

Comment: Thanks DRapp. Yours is noted. So, the CLICK event of the check box is a must? When I click a check box, the cursor moves to the next record, right?

Comment: @Sithu, if that is how you want to automate it as such... yes.

Comment: About AllowCellSelection, it is .T. by default which makes text boxes accessible. It is not what I want. Thus, my grid has "AllowCellSelection = .F.". If I add check boxes, I have to set it .T. which will make other controls accessible unnecessarily. Any idea?

Comment: @Sithu, You can always set all the OTHER columns to "ReadOnly = .T." so the user can not edit those, but leave the checkbox column as "ReadOnly = .F." so users CAN select/unselect that as needed.

Comment: Hi DRapp, I get back on this topic. ReadOnly = .T. makes the controls non-editable, but we can still access them, i.e., the mouse pointer is text and the pointer can still be placed in the text boxes. For my perspective, it is not a good idea actually. More doable by FoxPro?

Comment: @Sithu, Don't set the entire grid to read-only, just the OTHER columns to readonly, and leave the FIRST column (or whatever is used for the checkbox control) as NOT READONLY.  This way, the rest can't be changed, yet you CAN click a row for "selecting" which one(s) you want.

Comment: I know what you mean. What I'm saying is that cursor inserting point in text boxes although they are read-only. I think the only way is to replace text boxes with labels. Is it possible?

Comment: I got it. `Grid.Column.Enabled = .F.` or `Grid.SetAll('Style', 1, 'TEXTBOX')` prevents the cursor insert point.